# Mostrar resultado varchar en tipo int en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una consulta SQL y neecesito que si un campo tipo int Cantidad es igual a 1920 me de de resultado la palabra 'SI', como el tipo es int me da el error:

Error de conversión al convertir el valor varchar 'SI' al tipo de datos int.

Use algo asi CAST('SI' AS varchar(2)) para convertir el campo pero no me resulto; ¿Es posible hacer lo que necesito?, o ¿si existe alguna otra manera de convertirlo?

Gracias

```html
Select ...,(case when Cantidad=1920 then CAST('SI' AS varchar(2)) else Cantidad 
end) as Contratado
```

Comment: y si es mayor a 1920 qué debería entregar?, la cantidad?, como un string?

Comment: si no es 1920 es null, solo eso, si es 1920 debe mostrar 'SI'  y si es null, mostrar el null @Lamak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia tu expresión `CASE` por la siguiente:

```
SELECT ....,
       CASE WHEN Cantidad = 1920 THEN 'SI' ELSE NULL END Contratado
FROM ....
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

SELECT ...,
CASE
WHEN Cantidad=1920 THEN 'SI'
ELSE CAST(CANTIDAD AS VARCHAR(50)
END AS Contratado.**

en la condicion case, si no coincide cantidad con 1920 convierte el campo cantidad a una
variable tipo varchar(50), el valor 50 lo coloqué dependiendo del numero de caracteres del campo cantidad.
Me avisas como queda.¡